# How to use variable in return which defined in render React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to use variable sexname in return? have error "`sexname` is not defined ",how to resolve it?

```
render()
  {
    const { loading,popupVisible,edit } = this.state;
    const{information, about, data, photo,}=this.props;

    if(information.sex === 'w'){
      let sexname = 'женский'

    }else if(information.sex === 'm'){
      let sexname = 'мужской'

    }else {
      let sexname ='Пока не указано';

    }
return (
            <Aboutinfo>{

                information.sex !== null && information.sex !== undefined ?
                  sexname
                  : 'Пока не указано'

              }</Aboutinfo>
);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` is blocked scoped, so it is only available in the immediate block (a block is anything between `{ .... }`, which in your case is in the `if` statement, we can solve this by moving the `let sexname` to the top of the function.

```
 render()
  {
    const { loading,popupVisible,edit } = this.state;
    const{information, about, data, photo,}=this.props;
    let sexname = ""

    if(information.sex === 'w'){
      sexname = 'женский'

    }else if(information.sex === 'm'){
      sexname = 'мужской'

    }else {
      sexname ='Пока не указано';

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining it locally every time to it's own block, so it goes out of scope after every block `{}`. Move it below the `const` declarations and it should work.

```
let sexname;

...
else {
   sexname = ...;
}
```